# How to calculate the height of a cone at particular volume?

Tags: volume

The equation for the volume of a cone is $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$ starting from the base. However, I wanna calculate the height of the cone for a particular volume from the tip of the cone. Could you please help me with a formula? Thanks!

Update:
In the equation, r is measured from the base. But, I need to calculate the h1 from the tip for a given volume. But h1 is a portion of a cone, where I know the dimensions. I mean I know the values of h and r for the same cone, but I need to find out h1.

Comment: So to rephrase your question: Given that your know $\frac{\pi r^2}{3}h$, you want to calculate $h$?

Comment: In the equation, r is measured from the base. But, I need to calculate the h1 from the tip for a given volume. But h1 is a portion of a cone, where I know the dimensions. I mean I know the values of h and r for the same cone, but I need to find out h1.

Answer (score 1):

$$V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$

$$3V=\pi r^2h$$

$$\frac{3V}{\pi r^2}=h$$

Answer (score 1):

We assume $x$ to be volume so we need an equation for height . Thus $\frac{1}{3}πr^2.h=x$ thus $h=\frac{3x}{πr^2}$ plug in values and you get $h$. Hope i have correctly interpreted your question.